# Big-O multiplied by Big-Theta

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, computational-complexity

I have an algorithm that iterates for $\Theta(n)$ steps. Each step has a complexity $O(n^2)$.

The complexity of the algorithm is then given as $\Theta(n) \times O(n^2) = ?$

Is it valid to multiply Big-Theta and Big-O? If so, what is the product of the $\Theta(n) \times O(n^2)$? Since Big-O ignores all lower-order terms, my gut is telling me that it is just equal to $O(n^2)$.

Comment: It would become $O(n^3)$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It will be $O(n^3)$, and you cannot do any better as $f(n)= n$ is $\Theta(n)$ and $g(n) = n^2$ is $O(n^2)$ and their product is even $\Theta(n^3)$.

Comment: $\Theta(n) \cdot O(n^2)$ is not $\Theta(n^3)$, see counterexample in my answer, please.

Comment: @zkutch I also give a counterexample. I say it's $O(n^3)$ too.

Comment: You are correct, of course, when you are saying "it's $O(n^3)$". Here we are together. But I mean your words "..and their product is even $\Theta(n^3)$" - this one is not correct.

Comment: @zkutch $n^3$ is $\Theta(n^3)$ is in't it?

Comment: $\Theta(n) \cdot O(n^2)$ is not $\Theta(n^3) $ you are not agree?

Answer (score 1):

We can keep estimation only from above (right):
suppose we are working with non negative sequences and we have $f(n) \leqslant C \cdot n^2$ together with $C_1 n \leqslant g(n) \leqslant C_2 n$. Unique which we can state is $fg \leqslant C_0 n^3$. We cannot set left bound and say that $fg \in \Theta(n^3)$. Counterexample: $f(n)=n$ and $g(n)=\frac{1}{n^2}$. Obviously $f \in \Theta(n)$ and $g \in O(n^2)$, but product tends to zero.

So we can only state $$\Theta(n) \cdot O(n^2) \subset O(n^3)$$